# Regarding Html To Doc php script

Tags: php

I am trying to convert my html page to word doc file. But all php script converts to table based word document and my requirement is that the converted document should be in text based file means a doc file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused at what you're asking. So I will make a few assumptions and hope I'm answering your question.

You can explicitly state the headers in PHP such that the document you're generating should be viewed as a rich text document with the following line:

```
header("Content-type: text/richtext");
```

However, this will, in some browsers, prompt you to download the generated file to your computer, if instead you want to have a rich text file displayed right in your browser you can actually use the .rtf extensions on the PHP file to be run by PHP, but you have to specifically tell Apache (assuming you're using Apache) you want it to interpret RTF files. You can do this by editing your Apache config file and adding RTF like so:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4 .php .php3 .phtml .rtf
```

There are online tools that can help you "generate" Word Document files "on the fly" dynamically/programatically using special markup language. Google will help you find the various libraries. This one in particular, which I do not believe is free, has been used by a friend of mine in the past:

[rtf.generator](http://paggard.com/projects/rtf.generator/)

Hope this helps!